# iPad version of iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to release a separate iPhone and iPad app with the same bundle identifier so that both apps are related to one another. Or is the only way to this is to make sure that the app is a universal app. The reason I want two separate builds is that I want vastly different UI and capabilities for the iPad.

I realize that I could detect which device the user is on using `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom`however since I want such drastic differences I think it would be easier to manage with just two separate applications.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you want to develop two separate applications, what's the problem of using 2 different bundle ids? It would be like Skype is doing: "Skype" and "Skype for iPad"

Comment: @noir_eagle I could definitely do that however I was just curious about this alternate avenue as it would provide me with a bigger market presence for that one app. If I have the same app for both iPhone and iPad it creates more downloads which will increase search results for that app

Comment: the bundle ID is unique, so... you can either release _an_ iPhone and _an_ iPad app with _two_ different bundle IDs; or can create _a_ universal app, which uses the _same_ bundle ID.

Comment: @holex okay thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every app in the store is required to have an **Unique bundle ID**.You can make with little change

```
com.companyName.appName.iphone  
com.companyName.appName.ipad
```

As noir says give name as "appName" and "appName for iPad" - it looks professional.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I could argue with that statement: _"it looks professional."_ because the universal app is more professional than releasing two different apps as AppStore automatically shows the correct app for the current idiom, so the actual end-user does not really need to be aware of whether the current version has the title like _"XYZ for iPad"_, because e.g. if they are on iPad and the app is not for iPad, it will not appear as default – and the new AppStore Review guideline 2.3.7 explicitly explains why the title should contain the app's name *only* (also reduces the length of the title to 30).

Answer (score 1):

Two apps can't have the same bundle id, so you would have to use a different one if you still want to release separatedly. However, if you use storyboards for example, you can configure your project to use one for iPhone/iPod and another for iPad.